# undefined method `each' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails project, I use below code to retrieve data from `Assignmenttable` in database and show to user:

`views/assignmenttables/_form.html.erb`

```
<% task_list = Assignmenttable.find_by_current_user_id(user.id) %>
  <% if task_list.blank? %>
  <h1>It's blank</h1>
  <% else %>
    <% task_list.each do |task| %>
        <%= task.id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

data is retrive correctly from database, if `task_list` isn't empty this code is correct, but when `task_list` is empty, I get below error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Assignmenttable:0x000000069541c8>
```

how can I handle this error?

Comment: And also you have mistake into your problem description because i think when task_list will blank the it will not give error to you but when it's not blank then it will give you an error because find_by_something will always give only one record it need not required looping.

Comment: `find_by_` will be generate limit 1 record.. use `where` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've got is caused because the object you called the `.each` method for is not a collection (multiple) - it's singular

---

**Where**

The way to fix this is to either use the [`.where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) method to call your data:

```
<%= task_list = Assignmenttable.where(user_id: current_user.id) %>
```

--

**Associations**

Or a better way will be to refactor your code to use the ActiveRecord associations which make Rails so appealing:

```
#app/models/user.rb
has_many :assignments

#app/models/assignment.rb # -> notice the name
belongs_to :user

current_user.assignments #-> allows you to call this in views
```

--

**Model Names**

Another thing you need to consider is your model names need to use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (`AssignmentTable`)